# Make pie chart smaller Chart JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, size, chart.js, pie-chart

I have a Pie chart on my sharepoint Page that will not shrink. The smaller I make the px the bigger the chart gets. For example:

```
<canvas id="myChart2" width="200px" height="200px" ></canvas>
```

makes the chart huge while

```
<canvas id="myChart2" width="800px" height="200px" ></canvas>
```

makes the pie chart smaller.

The pie displays perfectly I just cant get it smaller.

I am using some java from Chart.JS.

HTML is:

```
<canvas id="myChart2" width="200px" height="200px" ></canvas>
```

The chart options are:

```
            var options = {
                tooltipEvents: [],
                showTooltips: true,
                onAnimationComplete: function() {
                    this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);
                },
                tooltipTemplate: "<%= label %> - <%= value %>",
                responsive: true,
                scaleBeginAtZero: true,
                // you don't have to define this here, it exists inside the global defaults
                legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
            }
            // context
            var ctxPTD = $("#myChart2").get(0).getContext("2d");

            // data
            var dataPTD = [{
                    label: "Active",
                    color: "#5093ce",
                    highlight: "#78acd9",
                    value: totalActive++
                },
                {
                    label: "Completed",
                    color: "#c7ccd1",
                    highlight: "#e3e6e8",
                    value: totalInActive++
                }
            ]

            var itemStatuses = new Chart(ctxPTD).Pie(dataPTD, options);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make the pie chart smaller, set `responsive` property to `false` in your chart options, like so ...

```
var options = {
  ...
  responsive: false,
  ...
}
```

Comment: i tried it that way. 

Setting responsive property to false did the trick.

Comment: Set aspectRatio: 3 in the options, it will make it small too.

Answer (score 1):

In `var ctxPTD = $("#myChart2").get(0).getContext("2d");`, you could use a HTML DOM element, not a jQuery element, and set height only like:

```
var ctxPTD = document.getElementById("myChart2");
ctxPTD.height = 200;
```

Hope it works.